PHANTOM WALLET CONNECTION IN SOLANA REACT
I want to connect my phantom wallet in solana for my website which I can open in mobile browser. Is their any guidance or example through which I can integrate that part. For my upcoming project. If possible share an example for the above case

Could you give more information?

use npm package @solana/wallet-adapter-react, @solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui
